# Is there a way to combine polylines on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, polyline

Context: I am building a map where train lines are displayed as polylines: [image][image]

What I want to achieve is that on the left, where the two lanes are merging, only one polyline is displayed, and potentially with changing colours depending on the number of polylines.

Is there a way to do that beyond splitting the 2 polylines in 3 with one different poly where there are 2 ?

Comment: Ah, symbolization of public transportation networks. You're looking for https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset .

Comment: @IvanSanchez, Thanks, that's a real nice tool, sadly it has a lot of bugs and slows the whole map :/